# Do I include Freelance experience on a resume?

Tags: software

I am currently working for MNC for 2+ years as software tester (2012-Present). Prior to that, I was with a start-up company and worked as full time freelancer for 1 year (from 2011-2012). Now, I am planning to switch to some other IT company.

**Should I include the freelancing period in my resume?** If yes, What do I do about my salary slips, since I used to get salary by hand? I have only an experience letter, joining, and relieving letter. And this job does not have an office anymore. What about address proofs and other items to show proof of my employment?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what to put on a resume for a *job*

Comment: And [Does this freelancing experience count on a resume for a full time job? How do I mention it?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/2393/152)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should include it. It was your work, but remote one. So do the same as in other work positions.

Regarding pay slips, if you have absolutely 0 proof from PayPal or bank, then either mention that your services were paid by hand. If possible, get official letter from that company stating that you worked from them.